# How can custom @EnableX annotation share its attributes with imported configuration?

Tags: java, spring

Here's a simple example

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableInteger
public class GenericTest {
    @Autowired
    // IntelliJ doesn't see my @Import so I suppress
    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
    Integer someInteger;

    @Test
    void test() {

    }

    @Configuration
    static class SomeConfig {
        @Bean
        Integer someInteger() {
            return 42;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(GenericTest.SomeConfig.class)
public @interface EnableInteger {
}
```

Suppose I want to make it fancier and be able to configure whether the injected integer is odd or even

```java
public @interface EnableInteger {
    boolean odd() default false;
}
```

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableInteger(odd = true)
public class GenericTest {
```

How can I share that attribute value with my `@Configuration` class? It's something that Spring manages to do somehow. Certainly I can do it too, can't I?

Comment: Included a working MRE so I hope my chances of getting an answer are now improved

Comment: Yes it is possible. Look for an example `EnableX` annotation from Spring and navigate.

Comment: @aksappy it's not very helpful

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible, and there are many approaches various use cases.

Here is one version of doing it. Please do not use this in production code.

```java
//EnableInteger.java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Import(IntegerBeanAutoConfiguration.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EnableInteger {
    boolean odd() default false;

    String value();
}
```

```java
//IntegerBean.java
public class IntegerBean {
    private final Integer value;
    private Boolean odd;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
//IntegerBeanAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils;
import org.springframework.core.type.filter.AnnotationTypeFilter;

@AutoConfiguration
public class IntegerBeanAutoConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public IntegerBean integerBean() throws ClassNotFoundException, MissingBeanException {
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
                new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);

        scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(EnableInteger.class));

        for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.spring")) {
            EnableInteger annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(Class.forName(bd.getBeanClassName()), EnableInteger.class);
            var odd = annotation.odd();
            var value = annotation.value();
            var bean = new IntegerBean(Integer.parseInt(value));
            bean.setOdd(odd);
            return bean;
        }
        throw new MissingBeanException();

    }


}
```

```java
//MyConfiguration.java
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@EnableInteger(value = "24", odd = true)
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private IntegerBean integerBean;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void post() {
        System.out.println("integerBean.getOdd() = " + integerBean.getOdd());
    }
}
```

Output

`integerBean.getOdd() = true`